# How can I prevent XSS for an keyup() jQuery event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

I am making a form with an keyup() event: every character the user types is immediately displayed into another div on the same page.

It's vulnerable to XSS. How can I secure it using jQuery?

Note: In my forms, I am using latin alphanumeric characters only, as well as commas, semi-colons, colons.

I have searched the "Reform" tool from OWASP but is there a way that's better?

Thanks in advance. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the few details available: remember that you don't have to use jQuery's HTML "parsing" for everything. Instead of using `.html()`, use DOM manipulations and `.text()` (which are also usually faster). For example, this:

```
$('#result').html('<span class="whatever">' + someInput + '</span>');
```

would become this:

```
$('#result').text($('<span>').addClass('whatever').text(someInput));
```

---

If that's not possible, you can also do flawless HTML escaping by setting with `.text()` and then fetching it with `.html()`. For example, this:

```
var data = 'This text: **is bold**';

$('#result').html(data.replace(/\*\*(.+?)\*\*/g, '<b>$1</b>'));
```

would become this:

```
var data = 'This text: **is bold**';

$('#result').html(data.replace(/\*\*(.+?)\*\*/g, function(x) {
    return '<b>' + $('<div>').text(x).html() + '</b>';
}));
```

Comment: Hi minitech, thanks for your response. Indeed I was using `html()` and using `text()` did it for me. Thanks for the additional info you provided, this is going to be useful too. Regards

Answer (score 1):

I've found the xss cleaner included in `node-validator` to be comprehensive. The code you're interested in is available [here](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator/blob/master/lib/xss.js).  You'll need to clean it up a little to use in the browser (remove the module.exports and wrap in a Javascript closure instead) but it should work pretty seamlessly.  If you wanted to, you could make it directly into a JQuery plug-in as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I am looking into that more in detail. Thanks for the link. Regards